# How to correctly use RTK Query (SSR) with Next.js to include tokens stored in cookies

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js, server-side-rendering, rtk-query

I have an application that uses Next.js, Redux, RTK Query and next-redux-wrapper and I'm having an issue with cookies not being available in a Next.js API route once `store.dispatch(getMedications.initiate())` runs - the cookie is undefined on server render, but can be read fine once the page loads.

On the same page I have a `useGetMedicationsQuery` hook that runs, which works completely fine and can access the cookies when the query is run, however whenever the `store.dispatch(getMedications.initiate())` query is run server side i.e. in the `getServerSideProps` the `token` cookie is `undefined`.

/pages/api/medications/get-medications.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default async (req, res) => {
    const SERVICE_HOST = process.env.SERVICE_HOST;
    const cookies = req.cookies;
    const token = cookies.token; // undefined when initiated via store.dispatch(getMedications.initiate())

    try {
        const response = await axios.get(`${SERVICE_HOST}/patient/medications`, {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
            }
        });

        res.status(200).json(response.data.data);
    } catch(error) {
        res.status(500).json(error.response);
    }
}
```

/services/medications.js

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query/react";
import { HYDRATE } from "next-redux-wrapper";

export const medicationApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: "medicationApi",
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
        baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3001/api/medications/',
    }),
    keepUnusedDataFor: 3600,
    extractRehydrationInfo(action, { reducerPath }) {
        if (action.type === HYDRATE) {
            return action.payload[medicationApi];
        }
    },
    tagTypes: ['Medications'],
    endpoints: (build) => ({
        getMedications: build.query({
            query: () => `get-medications/`,
            providesTags: () => ['Medications']
        }),
    }),
})

export const {
    useGetMedicationsQuery,
    util: { getRunningOperationPromises }
} = medicationApi;

export const { getMedications } = medicationApi.endpoints;
```

/pages/medications.js

```
export const getServerSideProps = wrapper.getServerSideProps(
    (store) => async ({ req, res }) => {
        const WEBSITE_URL = process.env.WEBSITE_URL;
        const SERVICE_HOST = process.env.SERVICE_HOST;
        const COOKIE_DOMAIN = process.env.COOKIE_DOMAIN || '';

        const cookies = cookie.parse(req.headers.cookie || '');
        const token = cookies.token;

        if (!token) {
            return {
                redirect: {
                    destination: `${WEBSITE_URL}/login/${queryString(req.url)}`,
                    permanent: false,
                }
            }
        }

        try {
            ... some stuff

            store.dispatch(getMedications.initiate());

            await Promise.all(getRunningOperationPromises());

            return {
                props: {
                }
            }
        } catch(error) {
            createTokenCookie(res, COOKIE_DOMAIN, '')

            return {
                redirect: {
                    destination: `${WEBSITE_URL}/login/`,
                    permanent: false,
                }
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Hi. Did you solve this? I am also using rtk query and next js and i need to pass the id of the page to my query and in the beginning the query runs with the id undefined. Is there a way to stop the query from running until i get the id ?

Answer (score 1):

```
extractRehydrationInfo(action, { reducerPath }) {
    if (action.type === HYDRATE) {
        return action.payload[medicationApi];
    }
},
```

this should be changed to

```
extractRehydrationInfo(action, { reducerPath }) {
    if (action.type === HYDRATE) {
        return action.payload[reducerPath];
    }
},
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).